# Messagebox function show error

Tags: c#, winforms, window

In my Windows application, I want to when ever user try to delete a row from `datagridview` then there should be a open a messagebox, asking user to confirm the deletion of that row.

For this purpose I have written this code:

```
DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

and check the user user response but this line shows error.

What is wrong with this code?

Please help me.

When I write only this code

```
MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure");
```

then it is working fine, but I want to confirm the user again so I want his response.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so you need to tell us what it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MessageBox API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  There is no method overload for `Show(String, MessageBoxButtons)`

I think you want

```
Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are almost there! If you want to specify `MessageBoxButtons` you need to add a title as well as a caption (or message text) in this manner:

```
MessageBox.Show(string, string, MessageBoxButtons);
```

Completed, your code should look something like this:

```
DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

You are getting the error, because your debugger is expecting a `string` for a Title and is receiving `MessageBoxButtons` instead. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MessageBoxResult instead:

```
MessageBoxResult res= MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

Comment: there is no object like
MessageboxResult .. i can't find it

Comment: i guess it's .net 4.5, the other posts show you correct method signature.  use that.